# Columnas y fila datagrid wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

tengo un datagrid editable en wpf, al escribir en una celda me pone ese mismo valor en la celda que sigue, en la misma fila, pero cuando tengo otra fila el valor de mi celda de la segunda fila lo pinta en la celda siguiente de la primer fila, como puedo hacer para que me pinte el mismo valor en la misma fila, adjunto imagen y código  de lo que tengo.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
private void cuenta_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        MaskedTextBox t2 = (MaskedTextBox)e.Source;

        string tex2 = t2.Text;

        try
        {
            var row_list = GetDataGridRows(Grd_Detalle_Provision); //metodo para obtener las filas de mi grid detalle_provision

            foreach (DataGridRow single_row in row_list) // recorro las filas que tiene el grid
            {



            if (single_row.IsSelected == true) // si al fila esta seleccionada 
            {
                TextBox t = FindChild<TextBox>(Grd_Detalle_Provision, "txt_nomCuenta"); // busco el texblock llamado txt_cuentaen el grid
                t.Text = tex2; // asigno lo que trae mi celda de numero de cuenta al texbox de nombre de la cuenta
            }

            }
        }

        catch
        {
            throw new Exception("Can't get access to DataGridRow");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Puedes mostrar el XAML asociado

Comment: Otra pregunta el metodo `FindChild` tu lo creaste puedes mostrarlo en ese caso

Answer (score 0):

desde el código XAML puedes hacer que se asigne a un control en específico el valor, por medio de un Binding.

```
<TextBox x:Name = "txtOriginal">
<TextBox Text= "{Binding ElementName=txtOriginal, Path=Text}">
```

Sí quieres saber más sobre Binding en WPF, aquí te dejo un par de links.

[Información sobre Binding 1](http://blog.scottlogic.com/2012/04/20/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-databinding-in-wpf-silverlight-and-wp7-part-two.html)

[Información de Microsoft Developer Network](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742167(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

C# y WPF utilitzan Bindings para establecer relaciones entre las vistas y los controles que se acutalizan diámicamente. Puedes usar-los siguiendo el siguiente tutorial, con una sencilla lógica puedes persistir esos resultados a la fuente de donde los sacaste.

En el siguiente tutorial se explican los bindings con DataGrids

https://wpftutorial.net/DataGrid.html

Seria algo así :

```
// Código
public Info{
  return GetDataGridRows(Grd_Detalle_Provision);
}

<!-- Vista -->
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Info}" />
```

Debes tener el Datagrid como propiedad accesible desde la vista, en el tutorial está bien explicado.

Espero que te sirva.